# Solve $n^4>3^n$

Tags: inequality

$n^4>3^n$

I'm trying to solve this inequality problem, but everything I can find online is either how to solve log inequality problems or exponent inequality problems.

I think this may be a combination of both of them, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: What is the range of $n$? The inequality does not hold for $n\geq 8$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The range of n is what I need to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Set $f(n) = n^4/3^n$. Then 
$$\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} = \frac{1}{3}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^4 < 1$$
for $n\geq 4$. Thus $f(n)$ is decreasing for $n \geq 4$. Since
$$f(8) = \frac{8^4}{3^8} = \left(\frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}\right)^8 < 1,$$
it follows that $f(n) < 1$ for all $n\geq 8$. The remaining cases can be checked by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (in view of the other ones), just a suggestion for future work.

Most questions of the form:

$$m^n<?>n^m$$

are quickly addressed as equivalent to:

$$m^{\frac{1}{m}}<?>n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

which is addressed by the behavior of:

$$f(x)=x^{1/x}$$

in its domain $(0,+\infty)$, with care to be taken at $x_0=e$.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^4>3^n\\
n^{\frac 1n}>3^\frac 14\\$$

Solving numerically, or better still, plotting graphs of LHS and RHS, will show that the inequality holds for $1.517<n<7.175$.

If $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ then 
$$2\leq n\leq 7$$

Comment: Thank you, but could you please provide the formulas you used to deduct $n^{\frac 1n} > 3^{\frac 14}$, and from that how did you get 1.517 < n < 7.175? If not plotting graphs.

Comment: @shengy: Just take both sides to the power of $1/(4n)$.

Comment: @celtschk - thanks, that's right. as for the second part it appears that a numerical approach is required.

Comment: @hypergeometric Could you write the details of the numerical approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the places where the equations are equal, you get three points.

I'm not sure how to find this, I'll edit the question if I find a way, but these 3 points are: ([source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5En%3Dn%5E4))

$$n=-\frac{4\text W\left(-\frac{\log 3}4\right)}{\log 3}\approx1.5167764122831706197$$
$$n=-\frac{4\text W\left(\frac{\log 3}4\right)}{\log 3}\approx-0.80224643154616987684$$
$$n=-\frac{4\text W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log 3}4\right)}{\log 3}\approx7.1747558273891581697$$

Where $\text W(x)$ is the [lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and $\text W_{-1}(x)$ is the analytic continuation of the lambert W function.

This gives rise to the two cases where the original equation is true.
$$n^4>3^n$$
$$\text{is true if}$$
$$-\frac{4\text W\left(-\frac{\log 3}4\right)}{\log 3} < n < -\frac{4\text W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log 3}4\right)}{\log 3}$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$n<-\frac{4\text W\left(\frac{\log 3}4\right)}{\log 3}$$